# Laravel redirect if account is not active

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i'll paste the code so you will understand what i want to do, basically i made a route filter and tell that i want to redirect if user's account is not activated (i make it via email link).

```
Route::filter('activated', function()
{
    if (Session::get('account_activated') == 0)
    {
        return Redirect::to('myaccount', 'MyAccountController@notActive');
    }
});

Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
    Route::get('myaccount', 'MyAccountController@index');
});
```

When i log in, i'm putting into the session the "account_activated" key with the value that is in the database (corresponding to the user) so...
when i try to enter here:

```
Route::group(array('before' => array('auth', 'activated')), function()
{
    // Only authenticated and activated users may enter...
    Route::get('sell', 'SellController@index');
});
```

I get this error: The HTTP status code "0" is not valid.
Anyone know why is that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use multiple filters for a route you have to put them in one string separated by a `|`.

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth|activated'), function()
{
    // Only authenticated and activated users may enter...
    Route::get('sell', 'SellController@index');
});
```

**Update:**
status code 0 means something went wrong when Laravel was executing the request. It is best to take a look in the Laravel log or the webserver log when this happens.

Answer (score 0):

after a while i ended up like this:

```
Route::filter('active', function()
{
    //if account was not activated via e-mail, redirect to activate message view
    if (Session::get('account_activated') != 1){
        return Redirect::action('NotActiveAccountController@index');
    }
});

Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
    Route::get('myaccount', 'MyAccountController@index');
    Route::get('account_not_active', 'NotActiveAccountController@index');
});

Route::group(array('before' => 'auth|active'), function()
{
    // Only authenticated and active users may enter...
    Route::get('sell', 'SellController@index');
});
```

thanks to jerodev for the answer :D